# Stack Overflow account details renewed

Tags: support, stack-overflow, user-accounts

My Stack Overflow account details are renewed, and my reputation, questions, answers and so on details are gone. When I open my profile page, it shows as new. Other associated Stack Exchange accounts are still there, like Area 51, and Travel. What happened to my account, my questions and so on?

What is the reason? I want my account back.

Comment: Try signing out, and signing in with various emails. Do you know which one you used to sign up?

Comment: If you cant restore you account, try contacting a moderator... And you must be knowing who are moderators, having ♦ next to their name.

Comment: @Anoop Vaidya: He should be contacting the Stack Exchange management, not us. And even if someone needs to contact a moderator, why is it important to know *who* the moderators are? You're never supposed to contact a specific moderator directly about moderation issues (unless they contact you first).

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: I have seen few comments as "moderator...plz see this". Also I tried to contact someone when I was serially downvoted :p

Comment: @Bolt can mods see [deleted accounts](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1255899/praba)? For some reason I never remember that detail.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: No, accounts are hard-deleted.

Comment: @Bolt that's a shame, that account did have what appear to be valid posts and many of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your old account was deleted. Here is a cached version: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:zwIMFb90mvcJ:stackoverflow.com/users/1255899/praba+site:stackoverflow.com+%22praba%22+%22iamtop.net%22&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk

Your old user ID in Stack Overflow is 1255899 so please put your email in [this form](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/other) and explain that you own the account on Stack Overflow with ID 1255899  and ask why it was deleted and if possible, to undelete it.